# OAuth2Decorator: Using developer's token to run API calls for user

Tags: api, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

For the "normal" oauth2 dance, I get to specify the user and get a corresponding token.
This allows me to make API calls masquerading as that user, i.e. on his behalf.

It can also allow the user to make calls masquerading as me.
A use case is bigquery where I don't have to grant table access to the user and I can specify my own preferred level of control.

Using the simplified OAuth2Decorator, I don't seem to have this option.
Am I right to say that?
Or is there a work-around?

In general, what is the best practice? To use the proper oauth (comprising of Flow, Credentials and Storage)? Or to use OAuth2Decorator.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, this [page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2) supposedly shows how to use oauth to get a token. Is this an Access Token or a Refresh Token? Does anyone have any sample codes for getting a Refresh Token and using it to get new Access Tokens?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use an OAuth2Decorator

Here is an example:

main.py

```
import bqclient
import httplib2
import os

from django.utils import simplejson as json
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets

PROJECT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
DATASET = "your_dataset"

QUERY = "select columns from dataset.table"

CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'client_secrets.json')

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
                  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

bq = bqclient.BigQueryClient(http, decorator)

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
     data = {'data': json.dumps(bq.Query(QUERY, PROJECT_ID))}
     template = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
     self.response.out.write(render(template, data))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

bqclient.py that gets imported in your main.py which handles BigQuery actions

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

class BigQueryClient(object):
    def __init__(self, http, decorator):
        """Creates the BigQuery client connection"""
        self.service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
        self.decorator = decorator

    def Query(self, query, project, timeout_ms=10):
        query_config = {
            'query': query,
            'timeoutMs': timeout_ms
         }
         decorated = self.decorator.http()
         queryReply = (self.service.jobs()
             .query(projectId=project, body=query_config)
             .execute(decorated))
         jobReference=queryReply['jobReference']
         while(not queryReply['jobComplete']):
             queryReply = self.service.jobs().getQueryResults(
                 projectId=jobReference['projectId'],
                 jobId=jobReference['jobId'],
                 timeoutMs=timeout_ms).execute(decorated)
         return queryReply
```

where all your authentication details are kept in a json file client_secrets.json

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback"],
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    }
}
```

finally, don't forget to add these lines to your app.yaml:

```
- url: /oauth2callback
  script: oauth2client/appengine.py
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand the use case, but if you are creating an application for others to use without their having to authorize access based on their own credentials,  I would recommend using App Engine service accounts.

An example of this type of auth flow is described in the [App Engine service accounts + Prediction API article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts).

Also, see [this part](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery#auth) and [this part](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery#ingestcsv) of the App Engine Datastore to BigQuery codelab, which also uses this authorization method.

The code might look something like this:

```
import httplib2

# Available in the google-api-python-client lib
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

# BigQuery Scope
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'

# Instantiate and authorize a BigQuery API client
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
bigquery_service = build("bigquery", "v2", http=http)

# Make some calls to the API
jobs = bigquery_service.jobs()
result = jobs.insert(projectId='some_project_id',body='etc, etc')
```